# Получить цифры из ссылки формата http://link.ru/id/123456/param/etc python

Tags: python, url

Как получить id (цифры после `/id/`) в `http://link.ru/id/123456/param/etc` на python3?

```
http://link.ru/id/123456/param/etc
http://link.ru/id/123456
```

То есть, из этих ссылок должно выводить `123456`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить эти цифры с помощью метода [re.search](https://pythonz.net/references/named/re.search/):

```py
import re


s = 'http://link.ru/id/123456/param/etc'

result = re.search(r'/id/(\d+)', s).group(1)

print(result) #=> 123456
```

Comment: не подойдет для ссылки `http://link.ru/id/123456`

Comment: @5c0rp да, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот:

```
s1 = 'http://link.ru/id/123456/param/etc'
s2 = 'http://link.ru/id/123456'

print(s1.split('/')[4])
print(s2.split('/')[4])
print(s2.split('/')[-1])
```

Comment: Для этого нужно чточно знать, на каком месте находятся эти цифры.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, надо знать. ТС не продемонстрировал контрпримеров, когда нужное число находится не на 4 позиции